# How to set up a user who doesn't have `admin` database access but use it as authentication database?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.0, mongodb-3.4

I want to setup a user in MongoDB. This user will not have admin database access. But it uses admin as authentication database. It will fail to connect the mongoDB by this command `mongo --host localhost admin`. Instead, it can use this command to connect to `test` database: `mongo --host localhost --authenticationDatabases admin test`.  How can I restrict the permission in this case?

I tried below command to create an user:

```
db.createUser({user: 'testUser', pwd: '123456', roles: [{role:'readWrite', db: 'SampleCollections'}]})
```

when I use that user account to login mongo shell, I am able to list the collections under `admin` database. How can I restrict the user only on `SampleCollections` database not `admin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not need. You just give user needed rights to the wanted non-admin database. User can use admin database as authentication database even user doesn't have read/write access to admin database.

```
use products
db.grantRolesToUser("productsUser",[ "readWrite" ])
```

[grantRolesToUser](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.grantRolesToUser/) documentation.

**UPDATE**

Let's create mongodb instance with --auth. Login as admin, create user what can readWrite ONLY test -db, authenticate with that user, check can use list admin database collections and what this user can do with test database.

```
#> mlaunch init --single --auth
launching: mongod on port 27017
Username "user", password "password"
#> mongo -u user -p password admin
MongoDB shell version v3.4.6
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/admin
MongoDB server version: 3.4.6
Mongo> db.createUser({user:"test", pwd:"testpwd", roles:[{role:"readWrite", db:"test"}]})
Successfully added user: {
    "user" : "test",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "test"
        }
    ]
}
Mongo> db.auth("test","testpwd")
1
Mongo> db
admin
Mongo> show collections
2017-09-11T19:06:22.001+0300 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: listCollections failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { listCollections: 1.0, filter: {} }",
    "code" : 13,
    "codeName" : "Unauthorized"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype._getCollectionInfosCommand@src/mongo/shell/db.js:807:1
DB.prototype.getCollectionInfos@src/mongo/shell/db.js:819:19
DB.prototype.getCollectionNames@src/mongo/shell/db.js:830:16
shellHelper.show@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:762:9
shellHelper@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:659:15
@(shellhelp2):1:1
Mongo> use test
switched to db test
Mongo> db.coll.insert({})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
Mongo> show collections
coll
Mongo>
```

And same from outside:

```
#> mongo -u test -p testpwd --authenticationDatabase test
MongoDB shell version v3.4.6
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.6
2017-09-11T19:17:48.614+0300 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1461:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2
exception: login failed
#> mongo -u test -p testpwd --authenticationDatabase admin test
MongoDB shell version v3.4.6
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test
MongoDB server version: 3.4.6
Mongo>
```

Comment: I tried to create an user with this role but the user can view the admin database. Please see the command I used on my post.

Comment: Remember to change that DB first, with that `use xxxx`, because that command gives rights to currently selected DB.

Comment: I have tried that. In this case, I need to use the `xxxx` as the authentication database. But what I want is to use `admin` as the authentication database.

Comment: @ZhaoYi check my edits at my answer.. There is step by step example. It works!

Answer (score 1):

@Zhao Yi,what you are looking ? I hope so that you shall find out your solution [Here](https://www.guru99.com/mongodb-create-user.html)

For example i am attaching a one example as shown below

[image]

The Explanation of the code is :

1. The first step is to specify the `username` and `password` which
   needs to be created.
2. The second step is to assign a role for the user which in this case
   since it needs to be a database administrator is assigned to the
   `userAdmin` role. This role allows the user to have administrative
   privileges only to the database
    specified in the db option.
3. The db parameter specifies the database to which the user should
   have administrative privileges on.

***Note:*** The output shows that a user called **Employeeadmin** was created and that user has privileges only on the **Employee** database.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can create a user with the role based on your command. But that user has access to `admin` database. I am able to `use admin` and run `show collections`. What I need is to use `admin` as an authentication database but restrict users only on `Employee` database. So I want this command for user to login: `mongo --username Employeeadmin --password 123456 --authenticationDatabase admin SampleCollections`

Comment: @Zhao Yi, As per mongodb documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/ Except for roles created in the admin database, a role can only include privileges that apply to its database and can only inherit from other roles in its database.